# Compilation fail at enableAutoManage in GoogleApiclient

Tags: android, google-signin

I updated my android studio version 3.2 to 3.4 now in my one of the previous project has a compilation fail. i didn't change any code. but i did update these dependencies in the app type gradle file (bellow) . the compile error says that first argument of the enableAutoManage must be FragmentActivity and i didn't parse it. but my Activity is a AppCompactActivity, therefore it is a FragmentActivity, because it extends the FragmentActivity.

Give me a solution for this matter.

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:18.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:18.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.zxing:core:3.3.0'

//compile error code "Wrong 1st argument type. Found: 
'com.airvapps.garythebot.StartTutorials', required: 
'androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity'"

gso = new 
GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestEmail()
                .build();
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .enableAutoManage(/*COMPILE ERROR */ this, new 
GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull 
ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
                    }
                }) 
                .addConnectionCallbacks(new 
GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks() {
                    @Override
                    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

                    }
                })
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                .build();
```

error: incompatible types: MainActivity cannot be converted to FragmentActivity

Comment: I couldn't mentions before, I changed the package name of that project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by adding these two lines in to the GRadle.Property file

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```